# Creating quartz job from xml string

Tags: xml, string, dynamic, quartz

I am working on a scheduler implementation that allows for creating job by reading job xml strings stored in the Database.
This would allow for updates to job xml at runtime in the Database where by post update i will need to update the jobs in the scheduler.

Is there any API in Quartz that allows for job creation by directly providing the job xml as a string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We found it best to dump the xml clob to a temp file and then use a wrapper around the XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin to load the temp files